# How do I downgrade a NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

after updating nuget package for solution front end completely goes wrong as under (nav-bar, slider everything).[image]

how to set it or restore nuget to previous version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project => Manage Nuget Packages
2. Choose the old version => Update

[image]

*Use source control's history, if you don't  remember what was the previous version.*

Comment: thanks buddy for your response but i tried it and it not works